# Adding a description for each image

Tags: flutter

I want to add a description of each image and do up and down the orders of the image with tiny icons.

[image]

I tried with [`multi_image_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker), but it has a limit to customizing. how can I make like uploaded image in flutter? Can't flutter make like that image?

Comment: I think [this](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customised the album, then you need to build your own album with this [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager):

get album photos by paged:

```
// page: The page number of the page, starting at 0.
// perPage: The number of pages per page.
final assetList = await path.getAssetListPaged(page, perPage);
```

once you got them, layout whatever you like, like left side image and right side description in rows

Comment: Thx! I will try. Do you have any example of using this package?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ListTile` widget for doing such things. The `ListTile` can have attributes like  `leading, title, subtitle and trailing`. So in your case, you can make the leading parameter equals to image and title will be the text which contains the description.

Sample code will look like this

```
ListTile(
        leading: Image(),
        title: Text('Description'),
        subtitle: Text('sub descrip')
        trailing: Icon(),
      )
```

Also, refer to the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

Comment: Thank u for answer. but that image situation is after when some images were picked. if i use multi_image_picker, i just add only images. but i want to add some texts each images(umm like textfield) like my uploaded image. What should i do?